# Where can I find the latest documentation for easyWSDL?

Tags: java, wsdl, easywsdl

I found the latest version of the easywsdl library at this link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.easywsdl/easywsdl-wsdl. However, I can't find any documentation or repository (like GitHub) for the latest version.

I did find a site related to the library at https://easywsdl.ow2.org/user-guides.html, but it hasn't been updated in a long time. Do you know of any site where I can check the latest information related to this library?

Please help.